# altacv + biblatex: publications not displaying/compiling

Tags: biblatex, bibtex, altacv

I'm using [`altacv`](https://github.com/liantze/AltaCV) to compile my Resume. My tex file is a minor transformation of the [`sample.tex`](https://github.com/liantze/AltaCV/blob/main/sample.tex) file included in the package. For some reason, I cannot get the publications to print correctly. I have the following:

#### `\nocite` or `\printbibliography`

```
\usepackage{biblatex}
\addbibresource{alex.bib}
\begin{document}

\begin{paracol}{2}
...

\cvsection{Publications}

\nocite{*} % alternatively: \printbibliography

\switchcolumn

...

\end{paracol}
\end{document}
```

Either choice results in the section heading "Publications" but no entries from the `alex.bib` file.

#### `\printbibliography[]{...}`

Instead of `\nocite{*}` I have also tried:

```
\printbibliography[heading=pubtype,title={\printinfo{\faFile*[regular]}{Articles}}, type=article]
\printbibliography[heading=pubtype,title={\printinfo{\faBook*[regular]}{Manuals}}, type=manual]
\printbibliography[heading=pubtype,title={\printinfo{\faMediumM*[regular]}{Misc}}, type=misc]
```

This produces the following error:

```
! Package biblatex Error: Heading 'pubtype' not found.

See the biblatex package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...

l.170 ...File*[regular]}{Articles}}, type=article]

? ^D
! Emergency stop.
 ...

l.170 ...File*[regular]}{Articles}}, type=article]

!  ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
```

My internet searching for solutions has come up without solutions. Any help much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add **both** `\printbibliography` and   `\nocite{*}`  to list all references included in your `.bib` file.

This is a simplified version of `sample.tex` included in the distribution. The `sample.bib` file is also included.

Run `pdflatex` + `biber` + `pdflatex` + `pdflatex` bring up the references.

```
% !TeX TS-program = pdflatex

\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{altacv}

\geometry{left=1.25cm,right=1.25cm,top=1.5cm,bottom=1.5cm,columnsep=1.2cm}

\usepackage{paracol}

% next commands taken from pubs-authoryear.cfg <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=apa6,sorting=ydnt]{biblatex}
\defbibheading{pubtype}{\cvsubsection{#1}}
\renewcommand{\bibsetup}{\vspace*{-\baselineskip}}
\AtEveryBibitem{\makebox[\bibhang][l]{\itemmarker}}
\setlength{\bibitemsep}{0.25\baselineskip}
\setlength{\bibhang}{1.25em}


%% sample.bib contains your publications
\addbibresource{sample.bib}

\begin{document}
\sffamily

\columnratio{0.6}   

\begin{paracol}{2}

    \cvsection{Publications}
    
    \nocite{*}
    
    \printbibliography[heading=pubtype,title={\printinfo{\faBook}{Books}},type=book]
    
    \divider
    
    \printbibliography[heading=pubtype,title={\printinfo{\faFile*[regular]}{Journal Articles}},type=article]
    
    \divider
    
    \printbibliography[heading=pubtype,title={\printinfo{\faUsers}{Conference Proceedings}},type=inproceedings]
\end{paracol}


\end{document}
```

[image: b]

The `biblatex` commands are those included in the file `pubs-authoryear.cfg`